# Autoit Library in Robotframework, cannot use "Send" Keyword

Tags: robotframework, autoit

I used to use "Send" as one of Autoit library in robotframework, but now I cannot find in in list of library keywords.

I am not sure what is the problem

I am using Robot V7

Comment: Did you install robotframework-autoitlibrary as Administrator ? See https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary/?tab=readme-ov-file#installation